# Using MAC address as a machine ID: will this change if the user installs vmware?

Tags: licensing, vmware

I would like to use network MAC addresses as a unique machine id for licensing purposes.  I gather this has some drawbacks though it is standard-ish practice (I can deal with client having to ask for an extra unlock code if they swap their network cards).

However, if a client installs vmware on their machine, doesn't this add virtual network interfaces?  And is there a way to distinguish these from the real ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the virtual mac addresses are in a specific range. Also, if they put it in a vmware box, and move it, often by default this wants to change their mac address too. They would need to be aware of that.

I dont have vmware on this machine to look up, but it starts with a specific code. Just as the Vms have a specific code too

Comment: you're absolutely right, the VMWare generated MACs have the same 3 or 4 segments at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

I think if you tell your program to always access the first network card, it doesn't matter if he adds more (be it real or virtual), unless he sets then as his first card.

Locking software to hardware is really inconvinient for the user and can cause them to stop using your software.

Have you considered authorizing your software using a webservice?

As in:

Client --> Web Service --> Database

The web service checks if the user entered the correct username/password, and returns true/false.

Anyway, if you really want to lock it to hardware, I suggest you actually take a mix of hardware ID like motherboard/cpu/harddrive.

You can find more information here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

Comment: That's a slight derail as I wasn't asking for opinions on the licensing approach ;-) though +1 because your first line is useful.  As you ask though: the trouble with a webservice is it's useless to a user who wants to work offline.  I'm going to authorize with a username and password then 'unlock' the specific machine.  They can put in the same username and password if they change the machine hardware, and use another of their unlocks.  This isn't that different to a webservice with a very long-lasting 'work offline' mode.

Comment: Ah, I understand. It sucks having to stay offline while not using your connection. I suggest you take a mix of hardware IDs like I mentioned :)

Comment: each MOBO around the world have one ID unique?